# How prevent reload entire page using __doPostBack?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, postback, autopostback

I am using a aspx page and inside a modal window i make __doPostBack, but this causes the entire page is reloaded.

I tried with:

1. `__doPostBack('<%= btn_search.UniqueID %>', "")`
2. `__doPostBack('<%= btn_search.ClientID %>', 'OnClick')`
3. `$('btn_search').trigger('click');`

also i tried with a  hidden button : `__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_search','')`

but the result its the same, all page is reloaded.

how can i prevent reload the entire page ?

```
    bootbox.dialog({
    title: "Validacion Paciente",
    message: "<input type='text' id='mensaje' class='border border-white' name='mensaje' style='display: none;'/><div id='content-capture' style='display: none;'> <div id='status'></div> <div id='imagediv' class='mb-2'></div> </div> <div id='Scores'>  <input type='hidden' id='qualityInputBox' size='10' style='background-color: #DCDCDC; text-align: center;'> </div>",        
    buttons: {
        main: {
            label: "Continuar",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function () {

                __doPostBack('<%=  btn_search.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');                    


            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Or better yet, learn how to use AJAX directly to make asynchronous requests.

Comment: UpdatePanel is being used. The case is as follows. I have many asp pages to modify developed by someone else, this include modify de code behind, this is not an option. Then, i need add a js file that create a modal window, this evaluate some things and after make the __doPostBack